# C# encoding conversion to UTF-8 - different behavior on Windows 7 vs. Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, windows-7, encoding, utf-8, windows-server-2008-r2

I am encountering some strange behavior between Windows platforms when it comes to encoding conversion to UTF-8.  If I have a string with "Extended ASCII" characters in it, say like character 0x99 for the trademark symbol, I can convert it on Windows 7 with the following code:

```
using System.Text;
...
string DefaultEncodedStr = <<Some string with Extended ASCII chars like 0x99 for TM>>
byte[] DefaultEncodedBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(DefaultEncodedStr);
byte[] UTF8EncodedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, DefaultEncodedBytes);
char[] UTF8Chars = new char[Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(UTF8EncodedBytes, 0, UTF8EncodedBytes.Length)];
UTF8.GetChars(UTF8EncodedBytes, 0, UTF8EncodedBytes.Length, UTF8Chars, 0);
string UTF8Str = new string(UTF8Chars);
```

However, this code fails to convert the initial string on Windows Server 2008 R2 -- the "Extended ASCII" characters are still present in the final string.

This code, however, does work on Windows Server 2008 R2:

```
using System.Text;
...
string DefaultEncodedStr = <<Some string with Extended ASCII chars like 0x99 for TM>>
byte[] DefaultEncodedBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(DefaultEncodedStr)
string UTF8Str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DefaultEncodedBytes);
```

BUT, this code fails to convert the string on Windows 7!!

What gives?  Why am I seeing different behavior between the Desktop class and the Server class OS that is using the same kernel base (Win7)?  Do I really need to include some kind of platform detection code to determine how to properly handle the encoding conversion??

Comment: How does it fail? Is the result incorrect, or do you get an exception? If the former, what did you expect? If the latter, what kind of exception and what does it say?

Comment: It would have been helpful if you provided a sample problem string, so people could just copy-paste to test.

Comment: Are there any differences on the machines with different language packs installed?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are not converting encodings - a string is a string. There is no such thing as UTF-8 String, or ASCII string. Strings don't have encoding semantics.

Comment: Please post a short but complete code sample that exemplifies the problem.

Comment: Character (byte) 0x99 is an invalid UTF-8 character.  If the encoding conversion fails, the final string still has this character.  If it succeeds. it is converted to its UTF-8 equivalent encoding.  I do not think I can put this character into the question :(

Comment: 0x99 is a byte value, if you have a byte array/stream with a byte 0x99 not lead by UTF-8 lead byte before, you would just decode that stream/array with Windows1252 and that's the whole story.

Comment: Since `Encoding.Default` is `An encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page.` you may have a problem with two differently configured machines, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET strings are sequences of Unicode characters. If you have a string

```
string s = "™";
```

then the string consists of the Unicode U+2122 TRADE MARK SIGN character.

So, equivalently you could write

```
string s = "\u2122";
```

You can convert this sequence of characters to a sequence of bytes using an encoding.

One encoding is UTF-8:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
// bytes == { 0xE2, 0x84, 0xA2 }
```

Another encoding is Windows-1252:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(s);
// bytes == { 0x99 }
```

So, if you have a sequence of bytes that represents a string in Windows-1252 and consists of the byte 0x99, you can decode it to a string as follows:

```
string result = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(bytes);
// result == "™"
```

[Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) returns the default encoding of the operating system. This may be Windows-1252, but doesn't have to. Always specify the encoding you want to use explicitly.

> Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can even change on a single computer. Therefore, data streamed from one computer to another or even retrieved at different times on the same computer might be translated incorrectly.

*See also:*

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: This. I'd like to also mention that there is no such thing as an X character, where X is an encoding or a character set. Characters
don't exclusively belong to a character set. ™ is included in over 20 different character sets for example.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.  The string that I am initially getting has apparently been "hard coded" to Windows-1252 but the Base OS doesn't know this just by using Encoding.Default, so I have to instruct the system to assume Windows-1252 for the initial string.  Thanks!

Comment: Strings do not have an encoding!! Only sequences of bytes that represent strings do.